# Vim command to go to the end of line number 

Tags: vim

I know the `gg` (or `G`) command in Vim, but is there a `gg` command combined with `$`? So basically a shortcut for that (if possible not a custom one).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't, AFAICT, except <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd> is like pressing <kbd>G</kbd> followed by <kbd>$</kbd>. You could remap <kbd>gg</kbd> and <kbd>G</kbd> (or any other key) to do what you want:

```
:noremap gg gg$
:noremap G G$
```

Comment: ah i know why it didn't work. I used ctrl-o for the command so it probably switched to insert mode after G